# Regular expression - Conditional Lookbehind, filter start?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm trying to do some checks on a string where I use a regular expression using a lookbehind and lookahead to retrieve a certain part of a piece of text. The typical format of the text is as below:

BS-123456.v2019

The portion of the text that I retrieve is 123456 using the following regex:

```
(?<=\-)(.*?)(?=\.v)
```

Basically I always want to retrieve the portion of the text between the hyphen '-' and the '.v' part.

This is working nicely.

I need to however make an adjustment to filter out any thing that starts with the word 'Copy', ignoring case. So for instance if I have the following text:

Copy_BS-123456.v2019

or Copy-BS-123456.v2019

or Copy BS-123456.v2019

and so forth the regex must return nothing.

I tried something along the lines of

```
^(?!Copy)(?<=\-)(.*?)(?=\.v)
```

but it doesn't seem to work. 
I'm relatively new to regex so please excuse me if I'm missing something obvious. Any suggestions or a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What language or code editor are you using? Only certain engines allow unbounded lookbehinds.

Comment: @KennethK - I was using C#. I realize I could have done it with string.StartsWith(string value), but I wanted to keep the entire extraction in regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part `(?!Copy)` of the pattern will succeed, but using the positive lookbehind `(?<=-)` directly after it will not get a match because the positive lookahead will assert directly after the start of the string that what is on the left should be a `-`

You could use a capturing group instead:

```
^(?!Copy).*?-(\d{6})\.v
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/thkqy4/1)

If there is only a single `-` before the number, you could also use a negated character class `[^` matching any char except `-` or a newline.

```
^(?!Copy)[^-\r\n]*-(\d{6})\.v
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e9aeHt/1)

**Note** that in your initial pattern, you can omit the capturing group to get a match only if you use the lookarounds `(?<=\-).*?(?=\.v)`

Comment: Nice, once again. I was puzzling myself and came up with `^(?!Copy).*?\K\d+(?=\.v)` as an alternative. Yours is simpler, and probably supported amongst more flavors.

Comment: @JvdV That would indeed also work if `\K` is supported.